# Netbeans Code Templates Formatting syntax

Tags: netbeans, syntax, code-formatting

I'd like to know what's the syntax or the language used to format the code templates in netbeans ide. I mean, in the default templates I can see things like;

```
while (${EXP default="exp"})
{ 
   ${selection line}${cursor} 
}
```

And:

```
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="${comment}">
${selection}${cursor}// </editor-fold>
```

And I experimented and did this:

```
int ${IDX newVarName default="loop"};

for (${IDX} = 0; ${IDX} < ${SIZE int default="size"}; ${IDX}++)
{
   ${cursor}
}
```

And it works but I don't really know where the **"${IDX}"** or the **"${SIZE int default="size"}"** or the **"${selection}${cursor}"** comes from and what other statements can I use to format my templates.

Is this some scripting or programming language?

Where can I find this information?

Answer (score 9):

I think Netbeans uses the template engine [Freemarker](http://freemarker.org/) for this. So all variables (= `${...}`) are filled in by Netbeans at the time you use the template.

Unfortunately I don't have a full list of all default variables / methods you can use, but here are two of them listed:

**`${cursor}`:**

> defines a position where the caret will be located after the editing
>   of the code template values finishes.

**`${selection}`:**

> defines a position for pasting the content of the editor selection.
>   This is used by so-called 'selection templates' that appear as hints
>   whenever the user selects some text in the editor.

*See here:* http://wiki.netbeans.org/Java_EditorUsersGuide#How_to_use_Code_Templates

`${IDX}` looks like a custom variable you use.

See also:
 - [Code Assistance in the NetBeans IDE Java Editor: A Reference Guide (Code Template)](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/editor-codereference.html#codetemplates)
 - [Code Templates in NetBeans IDE for PHP](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/code-templates.html)

Answer (score 3):

[How_to_use_Code_Templates](http://wiki.netbeans.org/Java_EditorUsersGuide#How_to_use_Code_Templates) pretty much covers everything there is.
Looking at [CodeTemplateParameter.java](http://codenav.org/code.html?project=/org/netbeans/api/org-netbeans-modules-editor-codetemplates/RELEASE70&path=/Source%20Packages/org.netbeans.lib.editor.codetemplates.spi/CodeTemplateParameter.java) shows there is another hint called "completionInvoke" which [requests showing of the code completion popup for the currently focused text component](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-netbeans-modules-editor-completion/org/netbeans/api/editor/completion/Completion.html#showCompletion%28%29), but that is all.